# Programmatically determining whether or not Exchange is installed

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

How can you programmatically by means of PowerShell or Batch scripting determine if Exchange is installed on a server or not? I have 225 servers among which I need to find all Exchange servers.

Comment: You should instead query Active Directory for Exchange Server objects than to check if Exchange is installed on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query Active Directory for Exchange servers (requires the Active Directory PowerShell module):

```
# Locate configuration naming context for the forest
$ConfigNC = Get-ADRootDSE | Select-Object -ExpandProperty configurationNamingContext
# Search for registered Exchange servers
$Servers  = Get-ADObject -Filter {objectClass -eq "msExchExchangeServer" -and objectClass -ne "msExchClientAccessArray"} -SearchBase $ConfigNC | Select Name
```

Answer (score 4):

From Exchange Management Shell (2007+).

```
Get-ExchangeServer
```

From PowerShell on the machine in question:

```
Get-Service -name MSExchangeServiceHost
# If it is not there then Exchange Server is not installed.
```

Alternatively - ask the Exchange Server admin team!